# ASP.NET angularjs redirect to another view of controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

How after click on button `Add` open View located at /Home/CreateItem. What i need to write in

```
$scope.Add = function() {
        console.log('working');
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MyScript/Custom.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="Second">
    <button ng-click="Add()">Add</button>
</div>
```

HomeController:

```
namespace MvcApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetData()
        {
            string data = "From controller";
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult CreateItem()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('Second', function ($scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.Add = function() {
        // How to redirect to Home/CreateItem ?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK

```
app.controller('Second', function ($scope, sharedProperties,$location) {
    $scope.Add = function() {
$location.path("/Home/CreateItem");
    }
});
```

BETTER

```
app.controller('Second',["$http","sharedProperties","$location", function ($scope, sharedProperties,$location) {
    $scope.Add = function() {
$location.path("/Home/CreateItem");
    }
}]);
```

The *Better* way is better, because it enables you to minify your angular code. By expliciting telling the angular engine that you are expecting `$http` as param 1 and `sharedProperties` as param2, a minifier can change those variable names to `x` and `y` thus making your javascript smaller.